# $location.path() doesn't work despite setting $apply() or $timeout

Tags: angularjs

I'm putting together my own Auth Service in an AngularJS application I am building and in my Controller I have the following code that calls a serive. The service deals with a log in, if there is a match I want to redirect to my home/main page... this is my Controller code

```
$scope.login = function (user) {
      // we have the user name and password let's see if account exists...
      AuthService.login(user).success(function (response) {

        // what have we received? if the length > 0 we have a match
        if (response.length !== 0) {
          StorageService.makeLocalKey('uuid', response[0].uuid); // this works!
          $location.path('/'); // the current path is /login, nothing happens, the browser path/ window doesn't change? 
          console.log($location.path()); // this gives '/' but I am not taken to main route and the URL isn't changed in the browser, it's still /login
        } else {
          $scope.errorNotFound = true;
        }

}
```

Now when I replace the `$location.path('/');` with

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
  $location.path('/');
});
```

I get the following error in the console: `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`

So I tried the following...

```
$timeout(function () {
  $location.path('/');
});
```

but nothing happens! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?  What browser are you using?  Any way you could reproduce in jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 38.0.2125.122 on OSX 10.10.1 and I am using html5 mode in my app

Comment: In the spirit of debugging the issue, have you tried calling replace?  $location.path('/').replace();

Comment: I sure have a still nothing happens. in my timeout I used $location.path('/').replace(); - perhaps I could put the $location.path('/') in the Service no the Controller?

Comment: @MikeSav did you ever find a solution to this, i have the identical issue

Answer (score 1):

Did you try giving the timeout a bit of a delay?

```
$timeout(function() {
  $location.path('/');
}, 100);
```

Or you could also try a combination of the two:

```
$timeout(function() {
  $location.path('/');
  $scope.$apply();
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

For two reasons you don't need to `$apply` the scope:

- $location solely performs `$apply` if needed
- You are inside controller and `$apply` is getting `$digest`ed for any
  changes in `$scope`
  I don't know all about your code but call replace() right after changing location to let the Angular know that rout is changed. this may solve.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue from a ng-click event from an  element. The cause was that the href="#" part of the  tag was causing a redirection before my $location.path('') code was executing.... Once I removed the href="#" attribute it worked fine.

Hope this helps other people.